# How to add percentage-of-height top/bottom margin in CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

What happen if a client wants a pixel perfect design, or in this case "percent perfect" like this example?

[image]

The full container is 100% height, so the sum of all divs and spaces results in 100% height.

The problem here is that i tried to add the spaces using margin-bottom in divs but realized that the percent margins don't represent the desired value inside the full container of 100% height.

The only solution that I know is using divs with % height instead of margins. But i want to do a cleaner html. Is there another alternative for this?

**Additional info:** I am using phonegap + ionic, is a mobile design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you will have to set the root element to `height:100vh`

Then use `:nth-child` to set the height and the margin of each divs

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{width: 100vw; height: 100vh; text-align: center}
body{padding: 0; margin:0}
div{
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  width: 480px;
}

div:first-child, div:nth-child(2){
  height: 15vh;
  margin: 0 0 2.5vh 0
}

div:nth-child(3){
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 0 0 5vh 0
}

div:nth-child(4){
  height: 30vh
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why there's a downvote spree in here.  The other two answers run into the issue of padding being based on width, but this one should work.  It's based on viewport height, which seems like what OP is after

Comment: Tambo, I was working on a demo fiddle, so please feel free to use this in your answer if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/c28h58cw/.  I think your solution is excellent.

Comment: That's really nice @JosephMarikle I prefer your fiddle post that as an answer ... also nice from Tambo solution :)

Comment: @JosephMarikle that is pretty much the same approach  but i prefer to use `vw,vh` units all over that way i am sure of the result. nice fiddle by the way

Comment: Thanks! i used vh and vw for fonts but never tried for this, good answer!

Comment: Never heard of vh... great answer.

Comment: @Aaron is a good solution for responsive fonts too, like this http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/ check the demo

Comment: @Bansoaistheanswer Sorry to dig up an old answer. Is there a way to get this to work with % instead of vh? [It's not working here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKwpJa)

Answer (score 3):

I was recommended to post my fiddle as an answer.  So here is the rundown:  The issue that OP is running into is that margin is calculated as a [percent of the width (See "<percentage>")](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) when you use percents.  That means that `margin-bottom: 50%` is 50% of the width of the container, not the height.  One way around this is to use `vh` (viewport height) unit of measure.  This is of course limited to a percent of the viewport and not a container, but as long as your design is essentially full screen with no scrolling, it's a possible solution (credit to the user [@Tambo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326135/854246) for coming up with it first).

Compatibility is also a concern (esspecially for IE): http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Here is the important part of the solution

```
.small {
    height: 15%;
    margin-bottom:2.5vh;
}

.medium {
    height: 20%;
    margin-bottom:5vh;
}

.large {
    height: 30%;
    margin-bottom:10vh;
}
```

And the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/c28h58cw/

Comment: Great answer, this is new to me, glad i stopped by to check how this one was going.

Comment: Yea, this help a lot, i am not a CSS beginner, but this is new to me. Dunno why some people downvote my question...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use common sense arithmetic and absolute positioning? You won't need to check browser support that way.

```css
div {
  background-color: #888;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  height: 15%;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 17.5%;
  height: 15%;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 35%;
  height: 20%;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Note that percentage top and bottom margins are relative to parent element's width, not height. Just another CSS WTF.

Answer (score -2):

you could use

```
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

which makes the height and width include any padding/borders, have a look http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `box-sizing` doesn't influence margins.

Comment: you're right and believe it or not, I knew that, meant to put padding but must have had margins going through my head, edited now anyhow.

Comment: maybe putting borer-box will generate enough space to put the margins ? There isn't any code up there to see so this might help.